# two header rows to one header row pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe that looks like this:

```
            min     max      mean       std       wav
symbol
1000038  0.0110  0.0022  0.003296 -0.002611  0.005514
1000043  0.0090  0.0102  0.004124 -0.000507  0.004847
1000055  0.0100  0.0030  0.001358 -0.001719  0.004363
1000059  0.0050  0.0017  0.003372 -0.001089  0.008595
1000060  0.0012  0.0062  0.002367  0.000407  0.006935
```

The rows headers are on two different rows, but are not *multi-index* as far as i am aware, so when i try to `columns.droplevel(0)` this fails with the error: `Cannot remove 1 levels from an index with 1 levels: at least one level must be left.`

The same `csv` file looks flat, like the below (but wish to avoid writing and reading back a csv) to correct the format.

```
symbol      min     max      mean       std       wav
1000038  0.0110  0.0022  0.003296 -0.002611  0.005514
1000043  0.0090  0.0102  0.004124 -0.000507  0.004847
1000055  0.0100  0.0030  0.001358 -0.001719  0.004363
1000059  0.0050  0.0017  0.003372 -0.001089  0.008595
1000060  0.0012  0.0062  0.002367  0.000407  0.006935
```

so my question is how to turn the above into a tidy (square) shape like the above with just one header row ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simply means your index has a name: "symbol". Try to [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

output:

```
symbol      min     max      mean       std       wav
1000038  0.0110  0.0022  0.003296 -0.002611  0.005514
1000043  0.0090  0.0102  0.004124 -0.000507  0.004847
1000055  0.0100  0.0030  0.001358 -0.001719  0.004363
1000059  0.0050  0.0017  0.003372 -0.001089  0.008595
1000060  0.0012  0.0062  0.002367  0.000407  0.006935
```

---

The dataframe diplayed in jupyter notebook.

One can clearly see the index in bold:

[image]

Same thing without the index name (`df.rename_axis(None)`):

[image]

and after `reset_index`, the index becomes a column and a new (range) index appears

[image]

Comment: this works:  For my understanding,  should one understand that an index name lives on a different row (*the second row*) to the columns names (*the first row*) ?

Comment: No, it's a metadata. It just **looks like** on a row when displayed as text.

Comment: @D.L You can access it with `df.index.name`

Comment: I will accept this as the given answer, but unclear as to why the metadata would exist on two different rows ? it is almost like the `index` is different to the data.

Comment: @D.L this is just a default representation to avoid confusion with the column names. Try to display your dataframe in a jupyter notebook to see the difference. I'll add images to clarify

Answer (score 3):

You can convert index with level `symbol` to column by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print (df.index.name)
symbol

print (df.columns.name)
None

df1 = df.reset_index()
print (df1)
    symbol     min     max      mean       std       wav
0  1000038  0.0110  0.0022  0.003296 -0.002611  0.005514
1  1000043  0.0090  0.0102  0.004124 -0.000507  0.004847
2  1000055  0.0100  0.0030  0.001358 -0.001719  0.004363
3  1000059  0.0050  0.0017  0.003372 -0.001089  0.008595
4  1000060  0.0012  0.0062  0.002367  0.000407  0.006935
```

but then get default index, `RangeIndex`.

```
print (df1.index)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5, step=1)
```

Then if write to file is possible omit indices:

```
df1.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

---

If need only display like square by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) - set index name to column name:

```
df2 = df.rename_axis(index=None, columns=df.index.name)
print (df2)
symbol      min     max      mean       std       wav
1000038  0.0110  0.0022  0.003296 -0.002611  0.005514
1000043  0.0090  0.0102  0.004124 -0.000507  0.004847
1000055  0.0100  0.0030  0.001358 -0.001719  0.004363
1000059  0.0050  0.0017  0.003372 -0.001089  0.008595
1000060  0.0012  0.0062  0.002367  0.000407  0.006935
```

but now first column is not column, it is index, only looks like column ;)

```
print (df2.index)
Int64Index([1000038, 1000043, 1000055, 1000059, 1000060], dtype='int64')

print (df2.columns)
Index(['min', 'max', 'mean', 'std', 'wav'], dtype='object', name='symbol')

print (df2.columns.name)
symbol
```

Comment: :D same second post

Comment: @mozway - one second faster ;D ;D